How to detect USB on Raspberry Pi and access it using Python?
I want to detect USB on Raspberry Pi and access USB to copy some data.
I used pyudev and get some info from USB but I can't access it. What should I do?
This is my code:
import pyudev
context = pyudev.Context()
for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='disk'):
    for props in device.properties:
        if device.get("ID_BUS") == "usb":
            print(props, device.get(props))

The path of the USB is /media/pi/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB_DV9 but I don't find it in list properties, when I print them out. How can I fix it?
Thanks.

so are you getting all the properties, but no sign of the usb path?

yes, I need get mounted USB path: /media/pi/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB_DV9.

The reason that you can't find the mount point of the usb drive is that device.properties doesn't include the mount point. You could however get the disk name (/dev/sdx) from device.properties and then use subprocess.check_output(['findmnt', '/dev/sdx1', '-no', 'TARGET']) you can find your mount point in the return of this function.
